# Two dynamic child routes - ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in angular js.

I have state defination as

```
  $stateProvider.state('main', {
  url:'/',
  templateUrl:'views/main.html',
  controller:'MainCtrl'
}).state('practice', {
    url:'/practice',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/practice.html',
    controller:'PracticeCtrl
    }
  }
)..state('practice.exam', {
    url:'/{examName}',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/exam.html',
    controller:'ExamCtrl'
    }
  }
).state('practice.exam.service', {
      url:'/{serviceName}',
      templateUrl:'views/practice/service.html',
      controller:'ServiceCtrl',

    }
  )
  .state('practice.exam.service.competitiveSamplePaper', {
      url:'/{samplePaperNumber}',
      templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html',
      controller:'CompetitiveSamplePaperCtrl'
    }
  )
  .state('practice.exam.service.subject', {
    url:'/{subjectName}',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html',
    controller:'SubjectCtrl'
  }
)
```

When I am hitting  ui-sref="practice.exam.service.subject({subjectName: 'Physics'})"

Both the template i.e `templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html'` 
and
`templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html'` gets  loaded. 
I want only `templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html'` to get loaded when i use 
`ui-sref="practice.exam.service.subject({subjectName: 'Physics'})"` .

Please help.

Comment: have you abstract state?

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: I am calling ui-sref="practice.exam.service.subject({subjectName: 'Physics'})", so i want only 'views/practice/subject.html' to get loaded but both the template gets loaded

Comment: you must create abstract state as your parent of state

Comment: please post full of states

Comment: $stateProvider.state('main', {
      url:'/',
      templateUrl:'views/main.html',
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    })

Comment: let me post the full routing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163539/discussion-between-aref-zamani-and-nitish-kumar).

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing..... Do you have state with name Practice?

Comment: after seeing the edited question you have declared all the state within practice except the main stage.... Do you want to open all the pages inside this html "templateUrl:'views/practice/practice.html'," ?

Comment: actually i hide parents once the child gets active using $state.$current.includes..

Comment: If you are hiding the pages then dont use dots in state name
practice.exam.service.competitiveSamplePaper instead use something like
practiceexamservicecompetitiveSamplePaper

Comment: The problems comes when I have two child routes of  practice.exam.service   like .state('practice.exam.service.competitiveSamplePaper', {
      url:'/{samplePaperNumber}',
      templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html',
      controller:'CompetitiveSamplePaperCtrl'
    }
  )
  .state('practice.exam.service.subject', {
    url:'/{subjectName}',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html',
    controller:'SubjectCtrl'
  }
) .

Comment: actually, you haven't declared any state as a parent .... as you haven't used abstract in state definition

Comment: If you are hiding the pages then dont use dots in state name practice.exam.service.competitiveSamplePaper instead use something like .. Good suggestion

Comment: actually, you haven't declared any state as a parent .... as you haven't used abstract in state definition  - using dot notation 'practice.exam' should be child of 'practice' state. right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163540/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-msd).

Answer (score 2):

add name for ui-view in your pages 
in practice.html:

```
<div ui-view="practice"></div>
```

views/practice/exam.html:

```
<div ui-view="practiceExam"></div>
```

views/practice/service.html:

```
<div ui-view="practiceExamService"></div>
```

and change your ui-router as following :

```
 $stateProvider.state('main', {
  url:'/',
  templateUrl:'views/main.html',
  controller:'MainCtrl'
}).state('practice', {
    url:'/practice',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/practice.html',
    controller:'PracticeCtrl
    }
  }
).state('practice.exam', {
    url:'/{examName}',
    view:{'practice':{ templateUrl:'views/practice/exam.html'}},
    controller:'ExamCtrl'
    }
  }
).state('practice.exam.service', {
      url:'/{serviceName}',
      view:{'practiceExam':{ templateUrl:'views/practice/service.html'}},
      templateUrl:'views/practice/service.html',
      controller:'ServiceCtrl',

    }
  )
  .state('practice.exam.service.competitiveSamplePaper', {
      url:'/{samplePaperNumber}',
      view:{'practiceExamService':{ templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html'}},
      templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html',
      controller:'CompetitiveSamplePaperCtrl'
    }
  )
  .state('practice.exam.service.subject', {
    url:'/{subjectName}',
 view:{'practiceExamService':{  templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html'}},
       controller:'SubjectCtrl'
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define Your state like this

```
$stateProvider.state('main', {
      url:'/',
      templateUrl:'views/main.html',
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    }).state('practice', {
        url:'/practice',
        templateUrl:'views/practice/practice.html',
        controller:'PracticeCtrl
        }
      }
)..state('practiceexam', {
    url:'/{examName}',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/exam.html',
    controller:'ExamCtrl'
    }
  }
).state('practiceexamservice', {
      url:'/{serviceName}',
      templateUrl:'views/practice/service.html',
      controller:'ServiceCtrl',

    }
  )
  .state('practiceexamservicecompetitiveSamplePaper', {
      url:'/{samplePaperNumber}',
      templateUrl:'views/practice/competitive_sample_paper.html',
      controller:'CompetitiveSamplePaperCtrl'
    }
  )
  .state('practiceexamservicesubject', {
    url:'/{subjectName}',
    templateUrl:'views/practice/subject.html',
    controller:'SubjectCtrl'
  }
)
```